# https connection and ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I have a site which is on HTTPS. There  I user jQuery AJAX to access webMethoid from the server. Is this webMethod called via HTTPS and is it safe?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this webMethod called via https

Yes. If it weren't, the ajax call would fail because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which requires that the document issuing the call and the call use the same protocol. (Unless you're using [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), of course).

> and is it safe ?

If by "safe" you mean "secured by SSL," yes.

If by "safe" you mean "safe from the user spoofing it" (for instance, repeatedly voting on a vote site), **no**, the user *can* spoof it, so checks for that sort of thing have to be server-side.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is on `https`, you can call your method also via `https`.
It's as safe as you make it by design. `SSL` is just part of your site's safety.